# Can't run WCF service on Local Machine

Tags: wcf, .net-4.0

I have a wcf service that will only work once I deploy it to a server and configure through IIS. there error message I get when running it through IIS express is:

> The authentication schemes configured on the host ('Ntlm, Anonymous') do not allow those configured on the binding 'BasicHttpBinding' ('Negotiate').  Please ensure that the SecurityMode is set to Transport or TransportCredentialOnly.  Additionally, this may be resolved by changing the authentication schemes for this application through the IIS management tool, through the ServiceHost.Authentication.AuthenticationSchemes property, in the application configuration file at the  element, by updating the ClientCredentialType property on the binding, or by adjusting the AuthenticationScheme property on the HttpTransportBindingElement.

My web.config  services binging looks like this:

```
 <services>
      <service name="LMS.Services.Services.AppService" behaviorConfiguration="LargeDataRequestBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttp_LargeDataRequestBinding" contract="LMS.Services.Services.AppService" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttp_LargeDataRequestBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service> </services>
```

and my binding looks like this:

```
   <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttp_LargeDataRequestBinding" receiveTimeout="01:00:00" sendTimeout="01:00:00" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />          
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" >              
            </transport>
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      <basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try changing this part. The issue is that the enum for Credential Type Windows maps to a protocol called Negotiate. IIS is informing you that Negotiate has not been enabled on your website, only Basic (no security) and Ntlm (another form of Windows Security) is allowed.

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>   
    <binding>      
      <security >
        <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" >              
        </transport>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

The WTF here is that there is a mismatch between "Negotiate" and "Windows".

Comment: That did make it work but caused another issue on the calling side Proxy service for a silverlight package. I am now getting this error: The message with Action 'urn:AppService/GetTemplatesByCategory' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.  Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (inc security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None

Comment: nevermind my last comment, I changed the url of the service in my client by mistake!

Comment: Hi Aron. There's a missing '/' in the closing basicHttpBinding tag. The typo causes the XML to be invalid. SO won't let me do a single-character edit or I'd just fix it myself.

Answer (score 1):

Updating IIS `Authentication` settings as below fixed it in my case:

- Anonymous Authentication: `Disabled`
- Windows Authentication: `Enabled`